# Android Studio says that my class is a functional interface

Tags: java

I was looking through some suggestions when I saw this:

```
//Original code:
endArm = new EndArmServoSubsystem(hardwareMap, () -> return arm.getServoPos());
//Suggested Code
endArm = new EndArmServoSubsystem(hardwareMap, arm::getServoPos);
```

However, this is what the class that 'arm' was an object of:

```
public LiftServoSubsystem(HardwareMap hardwareMap, DoubleSupplier scoreControl) {

        liftServo = new SimpleServo(hardwareMap, "servoLiftServo", 0, 360);
        control = scoreControl;
    }

public void setToGrab(){
    liftServo.setPosition(servoDirection*liftServoGrabPos);
}
public void setToScore(){
      liftServo.setPosition(liftServo.getPosition()+control.getAsDouble()* speed);
}
public double getServoPos(){
    return liftServo.getPosition();
}
public OutTakeCommands.Spot getSpot(){
    if (liftServo.getPosition() <= betweenGrabSwitchPos){
        return OutTakeCommands.Spot.GRAB;
    } else if (liftServo.getPosition() <= betweenSwitchScorePos ) {
        return OutTakeCommands.Spot.SWITCH;
    }
    return OutTakeCommands.Spot.SCORE;
}
```

As of my understanding, functional interfaces only have one method, and adding more methods makes the method reference throw an error. As you can see, it did not throw an error, and there were multiple methods. So what's happening?

Comment: `DoubleSupplier` is the functional interface. It doesn't matter what methods you have on `arm`. But I'm not sure what that has to do with method references specifically. And `() -> return arm.getServoPos` is not a valid lambda. Are you copying an anonymous class collapsed by your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
() -> return arm.getServoPos()
```

(I added the parentheses back, I assume you missed them when copy-pasting)

This is a function that, when called, invokes `getServoPos`. The syntax can be shortened to

```
arm::getServoPos
```

which is entirely equivalent. This is a shorter, more compact way to write the same thing. It's called a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

A *functional interface* is a different thing. I think you may have gotten your wires crossed. A *functional interface* is an interface which has one abstract method, and you can pass a lambda or a method reference as an argument of that type, letting Java construct the anonymous class for you. `arm::getServoPos` isn't trying to turn `arm` into a functional interface. It's creating a method reference to a *particular* method on `arm`, and that method reference can be used where a functional interface type is expected.

Comment: Ok, but when I tried to do the same for another method and object of a different class, it threw an error because the class wasn't a functional interface. Also thanks, I did forget the parenthesis.